# How to Display my output in Php with return in a loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to output my code. When I use return then it breaks up after 1time and

(when I use echo my content will be displayed on the top of the page. And I think that I should not use here echo because I want to call functions in the loop later)

Here are pictures that will show how it looks like:

My code with return:

```
function allmyshortcodesloopfunction() {
    $alltheshortcodes = '';
    $alltheshortcodes = 'thistextshouldbehere4times';

    for($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        echo '<p></p>';
        return $alltheshortcodes;
    }
}
```

How this looks: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3LQg.png)

how it looks with echo: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMjKb.png)

Maybe you can post a Thread which I could not find to solve this problem.
Some Tags for People in the future with this problem. That they can find this: 
loop, while, if, return, statement, content, breaks up, just one time, only 1 time

Answer (score 1):

Return exits the function, you can't have it in the loop. Store it separately and then reuse the function.

```
function allmyshortcodesloopfunction() {
    $output = '';
    $alltheshortcodes = 'thistextshouldbehere4times';

    for ($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        $output .= "<p>$alltheshortcodes</p>";
    }

    return $output;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. i have made a bit different : function allmyshortcodesloopfunction() {
 $alltheshortcodes = '';
 $alltheshortcodes = 'thistextshouldbehere4times';
 
 for($i=0; $i < 4; $i++) {
  $output .= '<p>hi</p>';
 }
 return $output;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
function allmyshortcodesloopfunction() {
    $alltheshortcodes = 'thistextshouldbehere4times';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
        echo "<p>$alltheshortcodes</p>";
    }
}
allmyshortcodesloopfunction();
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low value on stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.